# Golang WaitGroup causing memory leak, what can I do to improve this function

Tags: memory-leaks, go

I've been struggling to find a memory leak in our application and have been using the pprof tool to understand what's going on.

When I look at the heap, I constantly see the following function and I don't understand why (or if) it's actually a problem.

```
func CreateClients(raw []byte) bool {

    macs := []string{}
    conn := FormatConn(raw)

    if conn.Ap_Mac != "" {

        var wg sync.WaitGroup
        var array []Client

        c1 := make(chan Client)

        clients := FormatClients(conn)

        wg.Add(len(clients))

        for _, c := range clients {
            go func(d Client) {
                defer wg.Done()
                c1 <- UpdateClients(d)
            }(c)
        }

        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            for {
                select {
                case client := <-c1:
                    array = append(array, client)
                    macs = append(macs, client.Client_Mac)
                }
            }
        }()

        wg.Wait()
        // Do some other stuff
    ...
}
```

The UpdateClients function updates the client model in Mongo. When it returns, I need each client - so I can index it with ES plus I need an array of the macs to do some other stuff.

I've gone through the online examples and thought this was the recommended way to loop through a channel.

My pprof heap looks like this, and grows steadily over a few days:

```
7.53MB of 9.53MB total (79.00%)
Dropped 234 nodes (cum <= 0.05MB)
Showing top 5 nodes out of 28 (cum >= 1MB)
      flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
       2MB 21.00% 21.00%        2MB 21.00%  strings.Replace
    1.51MB 15.89% 36.89%     1.51MB 15.89%  github.com/PolkaSpots/worker/worker.func·006
    1.51MB 15.87% 52.76%     1.51MB 15.87%  github.com/PolkaSpots/worker/worker.func·008
    1.50MB 15.75% 68.51%     1.50MB 15.75%  newproc_m
       1MB 10.50% 79.00%        1MB 10.50%  gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson.(*decoder).readStr
```

Is there a more efficient / recommended way to achieve this?

**EDIT_**

As suggested, I've altered the loop as so

```
    done := make(chan bool)

    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case client := <-c1:
                array = append(array, client)
                macs = append(macs, client.Client_Mac)
            case <-done:
                return
            }
        }
    }()

    wg.Wait()
    close(done)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The receive loop never breaks:

```
  for {
            select {
            case client := <-c1:
            ...
   }
```

It has no stop condition, no timeout, nothing - so it will just hang there forever - even if your whole function exits. and it will leak both the goroutine and the channel.

On top of that, you're deferring a `wg.Done` when this loop exits, but you're not doing `wg.Add` to match it. So if this loop ever exits, you will panic.

What you need to do is find some way to stop the for/select loop. Simplest way IMO - add a second channel that receives data after `wg.Wait()`, but do not do `wg.Done()` in that goroutine.

Comment: I put the wg.Done() in this am after reading (a clearly wrong) blog... Ok, let me try your suggest - might need some code to demo. Thanks

Comment: Does the edit I made look like a viable solution? @Not_a_Golfer

Comment: Thanks, that was simple. Just testing live and my memory usage ain't growing. Thanks.

Comment: @simonmorley it's more idiomatic to send on the channel rather than closing it. Another option is to use `range` based iteration on the first channel, and close it, which will also cause the range loop to exit.

Comment: I see. I had actually been using range to start with but was sidetracked by something that said using the select loop would be faster and more efficient. Clearly not, if used incorrectly.

Comment: If using range, can we therefore get away without the need for a second channel?

Comment: @simonmorley yep. just close the original channel and the range loop will exit. same effect.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance.